# Bypass or force session authentication using Jsch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm using `com.jcraft.jsch.JSch` to create an SFTP connection.

Is there a way to bypass/skip the authenticity warning that pops up when the connection's authenticity can't be established?

Here's more detail:

My code looks a little like this:

```
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.connect();
```

When the `session.connect();` line is called, I get a popup that reads:

```
The authenticity of host <MY HOST> can't be established.
...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
[No] [Yes]
```

Is there a way to programmatically bypass/skip this popup and accept the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these examples from Jsch: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html You'll notice that both of them create a custom `UserInfo` class and pass it to the session object with `session.setUserInfo(UserInfo ui);`.

The way to avoid that popup window is to pass in your own `UserInfo` object. You can do this by extending the `UserInfo` class and overriding the `promptYesNo` function, like this:

```
public boolean promptYesNo(String str){ return true; }
```

Note that all of the functions whose names start with the word "prompt" are used to prompt the user for information with a popup dialog. You can override those functions to pass in the information in some other way.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is very old and doesn't require any reply if its already solved, But a week back I too was working on an application that had a similar requirement.

What Jon7 said was right; Adding to that theres a different way too i.e. without extending any class.

```
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
...
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(prop);
session.connect();
```

Just another way that can help others :)

regards,

icr